# select range for Pivot in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro for Pivot table with dynamic range. Pivot table is already made , I am just want to make Dynamic range selection macro. Range is A2:L
Please help Me how to create macro for just range selection and refresh All.

```
Sum of Amount in Document Currency      Document Currency   
Company Code    Trading Partner   BGN     EUR
BG05               CH10       272,326.08    1,618.00
HS03               RS31      1,618.00
```

Comment: Try creating a *Named Range* for your data, and then setting that *Named Range* as the source for your pivot table. Conditional Formatting can be used to highlight the named range so that you are sure that all of your data is being referenced.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens....I tried man codes from google but none of them worked with source and range name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code is Woking for me. Got resolution.

```
Sub ChangeCaches()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = Sheets("OPEN ITEMS DETAIL").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
PT.SourceData = Sheets("Download").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(True, True, xlR1C1, True)
End Sub
```